# mongoengine default value from another field

Tags: python, mongoengine

I'm trying out MongoEngine for a project and its quite good. I was wondering if it is possible to set a default value for a field from another field? Something like this

```
import mongoengine as me

class Company(me.Document):
    short_name = me.StringField(required=True)
    full_name = me.StringField(required=True, default=short_name)
```

this fails with an error `ValidationError (Company:None) (StringField only accepts string values: ['full_name'])`

:EDIT:

I did not mention that my app has a service layer which enabled me to simply do it like this:

```
if company_data['short_name'] is None:
            myCompany.full_name = company_data['short_name']


        obj = myCompany.save()
```

and it works quite nicely.

Comment: Mongoengine has a bunch of issues with circular dependencies. It might be possible, but you're probably better off doing this default on your end.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can override [`save()`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.Document.save) method on a `Document`:

```
class Company(me.Document):
    short_name = me.StringField(required=True)
    full_name = me.StringField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.full_name:
            self.full_name = self.short_name

        return super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Will this execute the rest of the overridden `save` method, like validation and the actual insert into a collection?

Comment: @ivica yup, it is handled by using `super()`. Though, better make sure it works for you - I haven't personally tested it.

Comment: I have tried it like you said and it does insert into the collection but returns None and I am unable to get the _id of the inserted document.

Comment: @ivica my bad, I was missing `return` statement. Give it another try. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#field-arguments:

You can achieve this by passing a function to default property of the field:

```
class ExampleFirst(Document):
    # Default an empty list
    values = ListField(IntField(), default=list)

class ExampleSecond(Document):
    # Default a set of values
    values = ListField(IntField(), default=lambda: [1,2,3])

class ExampleDangerous(Document):
    # This can make an .append call to  add values to the default (and all the following objects),
    # instead to just an object
    values = ListField(IntField(), default=[1,2,3])
```

Comment: Would this work for setting it to the value of another field?

Answer (score 0):

`default` does not get passed the instance of the document, so you won't be able to achieve what you want.

The `save` solution is ok, but the value of `full_name` is not set until there is a `save()` called.

Instead, use [mongoengine's `post_init` signal](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/signals.html#overview)

```
@mongonegine.post_init.connect_via(Company)
def set_full_name(sender, document, **kwargs):
    document.full_name = document.full_name or document.short_name
```

- Works for new inits and documents from queries
- The defaulted value is available immediately after init.

  ```
  Company(short_name='hello').full_name' == 'hello'
  ```