# Mongoengine - How to create a slug string field from name field?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, database

I have a model using Mongoengine here:

```
class Movies(BaseModel):
    movie_id = StringField(min_length=models.MOVIE_ID['MIN'], max_length=models.MOVIE_ID['MAX'], required=True)
    name = StringField(min_length=models.MOVIE_NAME['MIN'], max_length=models.MOVIE_NAME['MAX'], required=True)
    slug = StringField(default=None)
    description = StringField(max_length=models.DESCRIPTION['MAX'], default=None)
    views = IntField(default=0)
```

All I want to know is how to make that slug field autocomplete from the name field above? Is that possible? Thank you and sorry for my bad English!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongoengine default value from another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045429/mongoengine-default-value-from-another-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question should be something like this:
How to set a default value of a field to a value of another field in mongoengine?

A question like this has been answered here:
[mongoengine default value from another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045429/mongoengine-default-value-from-another-field)

So, in your case, the code can be something like this:

```
class Movies(BaseModel):
    movie_id = StringField(min_length=models.MOVIE_ID['MIN'], max_length=models.MOVIE_ID['MAX'], required=True)
    name = StringField(min_length=models.MOVIE_NAME['MIN'], max_length=models.MOVIE_NAME['MAX'], required=True)
    slug = StringField(default=None)
    description = StringField(max_length=models.DESCRIPTION['MAX'], default=None)
    views = IntField(default=0)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = self.name
    return super(Movies, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This way, you override the save method of Document class and add your default-setting functionality if slug is not set. The calling of save method of parent class (last line of code) do the rest for you.

Comment: Thank you...! You've saved my day :D